# Using translate function on more than data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

At the moment I'm using .filter to specific the type of data I would like in my data set. However, when it comes to positioning that specific, it comes through overlapping of course. For example:

```
.filter(function(d) {
    return d.Country === 'Russia';
})


.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    return "translate(-180,50)";
});
```

This of course just makes all that specific data go in one place over one another. I was therefore wondering if I could make multiple transform specified by the filter that I have. I attempted to do something like this:

```
.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    return if (d.name === 'Amy') { "translate(-180,50)"; }
})
```

Heres an example of my json etc.. http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/38/

If anyone could point me into the right direction that would be great

Comment: `.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    return if (d.name === 'Amy') { "translate(-180,50)"; }
})` should be `.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
   if (d.name === 'Amy') { return "translate(-180,50)"; }
})`

Comment: @jacktheripper .. thank you very much. Although, if I put something like: .attr("transform", function(d,i) { if (d.Name === 'Lewis') { return "translate(-170,90)"; }})
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) { if (d.Name === 'Amy') { return "translate(-250,90)"; }}) ... It seems to not work when the shapes are different? Any ideas

Comment: Why not: `.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    if (d.Name === 'Lewis') {
        return "translate(-170,90)";
    } else (d.Name === 'Amy') {
        return "translate(-250,90)";
    }
})​` ?

Comment: Nope it doesn't like it for some reason, you can try and edit on the jsfiddle i posted